# Homework till/on/for Monday

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

Could you explain to me the difference between these variants? Could there be more of them? What is a good guide (not a note-ish article) to use the correct prepositions with nouns of time?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Homework til Monday" means it's going to be a looooong weekend.

Comment: Please provide full sentences for your examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*till Monday* means that you expect to be working on the homework every day from now until Monday.

*on Monday* means you'll be working on the homework on Monday, it doesn't say anything about other days.

*for Monday* means that the homework is due on Monday, but doesn't specify when you'll work on it.